# Get HttpServletRequest attribute value using Spring annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a HandlerInterceptorAdaptor.preHandle() method that simplified looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {        
    request.setAttribute("MyObject", myObject);

    return true;
}
```

Next when my `@RestController` gets called, I would like it to look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity myMethod (MyObject myObject) {

}
```

I imagine there is some annotation I can put there where Spring will add the attribute I set earlier in the HandlerInterceptorAdaptor.

Could someone please tell me what that is?

Comment: What is the use case? Does myObject enrich the existing request body or just an additional metadata?

Answer (score 4):

Why not like this?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity myMethod (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     MyClass obj = (MyClass) request.getAttribute("myObject");
}
```